# Communicating with a hardware through RS485 Serial Cable

Tags: serial-port, communication, rs485

I have a smart electricity meter that connects to the pc through RS485 serial cable. This hardware has a software that you can read its internal registers and view them on the software. When I tried to read the registers of the meter through the software, I ran a serial port monitor software to sniff the bytes being sent and received to the meter.

This is the sniffing result:

```
Port opened

Request: 9/18/2012 7:04:04 PM.28064

 2F 3F 21 0D 0A                                     /?!..           

Answer: 9/18/2012 7:04:04 PM.70264 (+0.4219 seconds)

 2F 45 4C 53 35 5C 40 56 38 2E 32 30 20 20 20 20   /ELS5\@V8.20    
 20 20 20 20 20 0D 0A                                   ..         

Request: 9/18/2012 7:04:05 PM.53064 (+0.0156 seconds)

 06 30 35 30 0D 0A                                 .050..          

Answer: 9/18/2012 7:04:05 PM.06264 (+0.5313 seconds)

 02 43 2E 31 2E 30 28 33 35 30 36 34 32 36 37 29   .C.1.0(35064267)
 0D 0A 30 2E 30 2E 30 28 33 35 30 36 34 32 36 37   ..0.0.0(35064267
 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   00000000        
 29 0D 0A 30 2E 39 2E 31 28 31 39 30 32 33 37 29   )..0.9.1(190237)
 0D 0A 30 2E 39 2E 32 28 31 38 30 39 31 32 29 0D   ..0.9.2(180912).
 0A 31 2E 38 2E 30 28 30 30 30 30 30 32 36 2A 6B   .1.8.0(0000026*k
 57 68 29 0D 0A 31 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 31 28 30 30   Wh)..1.8.0*01(00
 30 30 30 32 36 2A 6B 57 68 29 0D 0A 31 2E 38 2E   00026*kWh)..1.8.
 30 2A 30 32 28 30 30 30 30 30 32 36 2A 6B 57 68   0*02(0000026*kWh
 29 0D 0A 31 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 33 28 30 30 30 30   )..1.8.0*03(0000
 30 32 36 2A 6B 57 68 29 0D 0A 31 2E 38 2E 30 2A   026*kWh)..1.8.0*
 30 34 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 57 68 29 0D   04(0000000*kWh).
 0A 32 2E 38 2E 30 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B   .2.8.0(0000000*k
 57 68 29 0D 0A 32 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 31 28 30 30   Wh)..2.8.0*01(00
 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 57 68 29 0D 0A 32 2E 38 2E   00000*kWh)..2.8.
 30 2A 30 32 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 57 68   0*02(0000000*kWh
 29 0D 0A 32 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 33 28 30 30 30 30   )..2.8.0*03(0000
 30 30 30 2A 6B 57 68 29 0D 0A 32 2E 38 2E 30 2A   000*kWh)..2.8.0*
 30 34 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 57 68 29 0D   04(0000000*kWh).
 0A 35 2E 38 2E 30 28 30 30 30 30 30 32 36 2A 6B   .5.8.0(0000026*k
 76 61 72 68 29 0D 0A 35 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 31 28   varh)..5.8.0*01(
 30 30 30 30 30 32 36 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29 0D 0A   0000026*kvarh)..
 35 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 32 28 30 30 30 30 30 32 36   5.8.0*02(0000026
 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29 0D 0A 35 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30   *kvarh)..5.8.0*0
 33 28 30 30 30 30 30 32 36 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29   3(0000026*kvarh)
 0D 0A 35 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 34 28 30 30 30 30 30   ..5.8.0*04(00000
 30 30 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29 0D 0A 36 2E 38 2E 30   00*kvarh)..6.8.0
 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29 0D   (0000000*kvarh).
 0A 36 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 31 28 30 30 30 30 30 30   .6.8.0*01(000000
 30 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29 0D 0A 36 2E 38 2E 30 2A   0*kvarh)..6.8.0*
 30 32 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 76 61 72 68   02(0000000*kvarh
 29 0D 0A 36 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 33 28 30 30 30 30   )..6.8.0*03(0000
 30 30 30 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29 0D 0A 36 2E 38 2E   000*kvarh)..6.8.
 30 2A 30 34 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 76 61   0*04(0000000*kva
 72 68 29 0D 0A 37 2E 38 2E 30 28 30 30 30 30 30   rh)..7.8.0(00000
 30 30 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29 0D 0A 37 2E 38 2E 30   00*kvarh)..7.8.0
 2A 30 31 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 76 61 72   *01(0000000*kvar
 68 29 0D 0A 37 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 32 28 30 30 30   h)..7.8.0*02(000
 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29 0D 0A 37 2E 38   0000*kvarh)..7.8
 2E 30 2A 30 33 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 76   .0*03(0000000*kv
 61 72 68 29 0D 0A 37 2E 38 2E 30 2A 30 34 28 30   arh)..7.8.0*04(0
 30 30 30 30 30 30 2A 6B 76 61 72 68 29 0D 0A 39   000000*kvarh)..9
 2E 36 2E 31 28 30 30 2E 30 30 2A 6B 56 41 29 28   .6.1(00.00*kVA)(
 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 29 0D 0A 39 2E 36   0000000000)..9.6
 2E 31 2A 30 31 28 30 30 2E 30 30 2A 6B 56 41 29   .1*01(00.00*kVA)
 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 29 0D 0A 39 2E   (0000000000)..9.
 36 2E 31 2A 30 32 28 30 30 2E 30 30 2A 6B 56 41   6.1*02(00.00*kVA
 29 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 29 0D 0A 39   )(0000000000)..9
 2E 36 2E 31 2A 30 33 28 30 30 2E 37 34 2A 6B 56   .6.1*03(00.74*kV
 41 29 28 30 34 30 35 31 32 30 30 30 30 29 0D 0A   A)(0405120000)..
 39 2E 36 2E 31 2A 30 34 28 30 30 2E 30 34 2A 6B   9.6.1*04(00.04*k
 56 41 29 28 33 30 30 34 31 32 32 33 30 30 29 0D   VA)(3004122300).
 0A 46 2E 46 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 29 0D 0A   .F.F(00000000)..
 46 2E 46 2E 31 28 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 29 0D   F.F.1(00010000).
 0A 46 2E 46 2E 32 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 29   .F.F.2(00000000)
 0D 0A 46 2E 46 2E 33 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   ..F.F.3(00000000
 29 0D 0A 43 2E 33 2E 30 28 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   )..C.3.0(0000000
 30 29 0D 0A 43 2E 35 36 28 30 30 33 37 32 35 29   0)..C.56(003725)
 0D 0A 21 0D 0A 03 6F                              ..!...o         

Port closed
```

My question: Is it possible to send the request bytes (which were found above) to the meter and then get the answer bytes and saved them on pc? Basically, is it possible to communicate with the meter by sending the hex bytes and receiving the answer? or there are some other steps that is necessary to do before sending hex bytes?

Note: My aim is to develop a basic and simpler software as the software provided with the meter.

Comment: You can just send and receive the ASCII strings (displayed on the right of your dump) - this should be quite easy to do - did you have a specific question ?